How can an executable modify its caller's bash history?
I have a program which can be invoked with an ncurses TUI (no arguments), or with arguments.
The effect of myprog foo is the same as running myprog and choosing foo from the menu.
When a user runs myprog and chooses foo, I would like to replace the last myprog entry in their bash history with myprog foo, so that they can repeat the action without having to go back into the TUI and choose foo again.
Note: I am not asking about modifying the .bash_history file.  I need to find a mechanism for replacing the last (in-memory) history command in the parent bash process.
How can I replace the last entry in the calling bash process' history?

You can't. Consider distributing a completion script along with your program instead

That's counterintuitive. If i type myprog i want to have myprog in history, not anything else. Predictability is way more valued than such improvements. After typing myprog and choosing foo in a gui, i would to repeat the process again, press up and enter and choose foo in a gui. Different users prefer different interfaces, it's much better to stick to existing conventions and offer predictable consistent repeatable behavior. I would only present a helpfull hint to the user in the gui that like some same behavior can be done with such and such command line.

@KamilCuk - Thanks, I will rethink this.

If it is really important for individual users (e.g. yourself), you might be able to implement this as a wrapper in bash by overriding myprog with a bash alias/function which 1. calls the external command myprog, 2. removes itself from the history (see help history), 3. reads a custom history file created by myprog, and 4. puts the equivalent bash command (e.g. myprog foo) into bash's history.
